# Laravel Homestead: Adding an additional virtual machine using vagrant box

Tags: laravel-4

There has been a recent change lately when attempting to clone the laravel/homestead package from GitHub.  I haven't had trouble in the past trying to add additional virtual machines to my system but now I'm running into a problem.

If you go into GitHub to look at the latest repository for [Laravel Homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead) you will see that the '**homestead.yaml**' file is not in the root directory any longer and has now been replaced by the file '**homestead**'.

In the past, I have used the steps below for creating additional virtual machines in my command prompt:

1) Create a new directory (Code2) from within the root directory where VirtualBox and VagrantBox are installed
2) Go into 'cmd' and change to 'Code2' directory
3) Type in '**vagrant box add laravel/homestead --force**'
4) Type in '**git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead_temp**'
5) Go into the newly created '**Homestead_temp**' directory, copy and paste the files from inside that directory into your '**Code2**' root directory.
6) Edit '**src/stubs/homestead.yaml**' so that it contains the correct paths for your '**Code2**' directory.
7) Go back into '**cmd**' and type in '**vagrant up**'.  When I try to do this, I keep getting a '**read: No such file or directory C:/Users/Jeff/.homestead/Homestead.yaml**'

I haven't had trouble in the past adding additional virtual machines but now I am prevented from doing so.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this answers my question or not, I'll have to do some research on it but for anybody that is curious about the recent Laravel Homestead changes, check out this article for [Laravel 2.0](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-homestead-2.0)

Hope this information helps!